# Duration of Pending Flags

Tags: discussion, support, questions, flags

I flag some of the posts on june 21 and june 22 the link is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37939881/android-fragment-animation-layer) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37963114/org-hibernate-invalidmappingexception-could-not-parse-mapping-document-from-res) one of the post is flagged as `duplicate of` and the other question has 6 negative votes and is flagged as `unclear what you're asking`  **But** even 9 day now the posts are not reviewed for the flags. I want to know how many days a flag took for review normally.
Before these flags I notice the flag reviewed within 2 to 3 days.

Comment: Sometimes flags end up aging away. There's just not enough users with enough rep to deal with all of them.

Comment: @BSMP I think there is enough users with enough rep but they just chose not to use their moderation powers.

Comment: Strangely enough, the answer seems to be OK. If only its owner had a bit more sense to not answer crap...

Comment: The first one has a quiet combination of tags (note there's no programming language specified). That one fell out of the close queue after 4 days (Into review on the 21st at 9:44 GMT, review invalidated on the 25th just after midnight GMT). The second was (IMHO) improperly handled in the triage queue (3x needs editing, 2x unsalvagable).